# Instead of linking with lws2_32 , which library is missing?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, cygwin, tcp

I am begining with socket programing and I am able to compile my program correctly without any error i.e the command

```
gcc -c file_name.c
```

gives no error but when I try to link it with libraries and try to create an executable file for running my code i.e by

```
gcc file_namme.o -o file_name -lws2_32
```

it throws an error of undefined reference to inet_pton , I want to know which linking library I am missing and why this error is there

My code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
WSADATA wsaData;
void diewithusermsg(const char* msg , const char* detail);
void diewithsysmsg(const char* msg);
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
 {

if(argc<3 || argc>4)
{
    diewithusermsg("Parameters","<server address> <Echo String> <port      number>");
}
char* servip=argv[1];
char* echostring=argv[2];
 uint16_t servport=(argc==4)?atoi(argv[3]):7;
 int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock<0){
        diewithsysmsg("socket() failed");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET,servip,&servAddr.sin_addr.S_un);
}
void diewithusermsg(const char* msg, const char* detail)
{
fputs(msg,stderr);
fputs(":",stderr);
fputs(detail,stderr);
fputs("\n",stderr);
exit(1);
}
void diewithsysmsg(const char*msg)
{perror(msg);
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz even I mentioned the same , doing it as file_name.c encryptes it into editable format of understandable format i.e machine code , but I am looking for  the library I am missing ?

Comment: Try replacing `inet_pton` with `InetPton`

Comment: I had already tried it , then it says undefiened reference to InetPton , even the microsoft documentary of inet_pton does not tell anything else which I haven't mention

Comment: You should compile with "-Wall -Wextra" options to see if some functions are not declared

Comment: @purplepsycho no effect , the same error persist

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) appropriate vertical and horizontal spacing (blank lines and spaces) should be used.

Comment: Your compiler and the associated header files may be too old. For example, gcc 4.8.3 (mingw) does not have that `inet_pton`, but 4.9.1 does have.

Answer (score 1):

The program you are writing in not a cygwin (unix)  one, but a pure windows one. As such you can not use the gcc compiler but the mingw64 cross compiler (cygwin to mingw64)

Install mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core (or mingw64-i686-gcc-core), depending on your arch and use x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe (or i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe) as compiler.